# ContentControl won't use DataTemplates

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, win-universal-app, uwp

I have two models that i want to represent as directories and files. The models both implement an interface which contains a property `string Name {get;}`.

```
public interface INode
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Path { get; }
}

public class Directory : INode
{
    public Directory(string name, string path)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Path = path;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string Path { get; }
}

public class File : INode
{
    public File(string name, string path)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Path = path;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string Path { get; }
}
```

I created two `DataTemplates`, one for each `INode` implementation. Each template has a `ContentControl` to render a `Path`, and a `TextBlock` to render the `INode.Name` property.

```
<views:NavigationAwarePage
    x:Class="OpenTasks.Views.ProviderDirectoryBrowserPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="using:OpenTasks.Views"
    xmlns:models="using:OpenTasks.DomainLogic">

    <views:NavigationAwarePage.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderIconTemplate">
            <Path Data="M10,4H4C2.89,4 2,4.89 2,6V18A2,2 0 0,0 4,20H20A2,2 0 0,0 22,18V8C22,6.89 21.1,6 20,6H12L10,4Z" 
                          Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="96"
                          Height="96">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FileIconTemplate">
            <Path Data="M13,9H18.5L13,3.5V9M6,2H14L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V4C4,2.89 4.89,2 6,2M11,4H6V20H11L18,20V11H11V4Z"
                          Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="96"
                          Height="96">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Directory"
                              x:Key="DirectoryItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FolderIconTemplate}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:File"
                              x:Key="FileItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIconTemplate}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </views:NavigationAwarePage.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentsOfPath}" />
    </Grid>
</views:NavigationAwarePage>
```

I then databound a `ListView` to a `List<INode>` collection. The problem however is that the `ListView` just renders the `ToString()` version of the `INode` implementation, instead of using the `DataTemplate`.

[image]

Why does the `ListView` not properly use one of the `DataTemplate`s I have defined? I have also put together a `DataTemplateSelector`, but the ListView still does not use one of my templates.

```
public class DirectoryListingTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DirectoryTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if (item is File)
        {
            return FileTemplate;
        }

        return DirectoryTemplate;
    }
}

<views:NavigationAwarePage.Resources>
    <views:DirectoryListingTemplateSelector x:Key="DirectoryListingSelector" 
                                        FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileItemTemplate}"
                                        DirectoryTemplate="{StaticResource DirectoryItemTemplate}" />


<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentsOfPath}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DirectoryListingSelector}" />
```

Do `UWP` apps handle `DataTemplate`s differently than `WPF` does? I've noticed I can't define a template without specifying a key, even if I specify a `DataType`. I'm not sure what other differences there may be that's causing this problem for me. This exact example is working fine for me in a WPF app, so the issue is specific to `UWP`.

### Edit

I'm not sure why it wasn't working the first time I tried, but the template selector now works. I'd prefer not to write template selectors for every `ContentControl` or `ItemsControl` that can support more than one template. Are template selectors the only way to go in `UWP`?

```
<views:NavigationAwarePage
    x:Class="OpenTasks.Views.ProviderDirectoryBrowserPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="using:OpenTasks.Views"
    xmlns:models="using:OpenTasks.DomainLogic"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:OpenTasks.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="viewModels:ProviderDirectoryBrowserViewModelDesignData">

    <views:NavigationAwarePage.Resources>
        <views:DirectoryListingTemplateSelector x:Key="DirectoryListingSelector" 
                                                FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileItemTemplate}"
                                                DirectoryTemplate="{StaticResource DirectoryItemTemplate}" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderIconTemplate">
            <Path Data="M10,4H4C2.89,4 2,4.89 2,6V18A2,2 0 0,0 4,20H20A2,2 0 0,0 22,18V8C22,6.89 21.1,6 20,6H12L10,4Z" 
                  Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="24"
                  Height="24" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FileIconTemplate">
            <Path Data="M13,9H18.5L13,3.5V9M6,2H14L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V4C4,2.89 4.89,2 6,2M11,4H6V20H11L18,20V11H11V4Z"
                  Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="24"
                  Height="24" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Directory"
                      x:Key="DirectoryItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FolderIconTemplate}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:File"
                      x:Key="FileItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FileIconTemplate}" 
                                Margin="0 0 10 0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </views:NavigationAwarePage.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentsOfPath}"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DirectoryListingSelector}" />
    </Grid>
</views:NavigationAwarePage>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say there's a few ways to tackle this issue. In your case, I'd be tempted to use a custom converter and assign your icon templates to it.

The converter could look like:

```
public class FileIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public DataTemplate FileIconTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate FolderIconTemplate { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is Directory)
        {
            return this.FolderIconTemplate;
        }

        if (value is File)
        {
            return this.FileIconTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, in the page resources, create the converter and assign the icon templates:

```
<local:FileIconConverter x:Key="FileIconConverter">
    <local:FileIconConverter.FileIconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="M13,9H18.5L13,3.5V9M6,2H14L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V4C4,2.89 4.89,2 6,2M11,4H6V20H11L18,20V11H11V4Z"
                    Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Width="96"
                    Height="96">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:FileIconConverter.FileIconTemplate>
    <local:FileIconConverter.FolderIconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="M10,4H4C2.89,4 2,4.89 2,6V18A2,2 0 0,0 4,20H20A2,2 0 0,0 22,18V8C22,6.89 21.1,6 20,6H12L10,4Z" 
                        Fill="{StaticResource AppTint}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Width="96"
                        Height="96">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:FileIconConverter.FolderIconTemplate>
</local:FileIconConverter>
```

Lastly, in your listview, bind your data and use the converter:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FileIconConverter}}" 
                            Margin="0 0 10 0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: How does this differ from using a `DataTemplateSelector`? I'd like to know why you would use a convert to handle switching between templates, over a template selector

Comment: Two reasons: 1/ Performance: using a datatemplateselector kills items recycling because it prevents caching (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx#use_item_template_selectors_only_as_needed), though arguably my solution needs to realize templates as well, even if they're smaller, 2/ Maintainability: I'm not duplicating the main item template, so it's way easier to add more icon types. You could push the concept further by binding the `Data` of the Path instead of the whole control