# Dynamically change DataTemplate for a ListView at Runtime

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have 2 DataTemplates for displaying the contents of ClassA or ClassB inside a single ListView; which template to select will be based on a RadioButton selection by the user.

Is it possible to change the ItemTemplate of a ListView (in XAML) based on user input dynamically at runtime?

An example snippet of code:

XAML Page:

```
<Page...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ClassAListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:ClassA" ... />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ClassBListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:ClassB" ... />    
    </Page.Resources>
    <RelativePanel>
        <RadioButton Content="ClassA" ... />
        <RadioButton Content="ClassB" ... />
        <ListView DataContext="{Binding Path=MainViewModel}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfClassAOrB, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClassAListViewItemTemplate}"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

I have stripped the code down somewhat to the essentials, but I would like to be able to change the following at runtime:

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClassAListViewItemTemplate}"
```

I have seen solutions for Classic WPF applications that use Style.Triggers, but these aren't applicable for UWP

Marco Minerva's blog on [Adaptive Triggers, RelativePanel and DataTemplate in the Universal Windows Platform](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/adaptive-triggers-relativepanel-and-datatemplate-in-universal-windows-platform/) talks of using UserControls within DataTemplates to modify the visual state using Adaptive Triggers, but this doesn't take into account switching out of templates based on user input

The closest answer I have found to my problem is another blog he wrote "[Dynamically choose DataTemplate in WinRT](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/dynamically-choose-datatemplate-in-winrt/)" where there is an element of code-behind involved - but it only appears to be an if statement - but its the cleanest solution I have come across thus far, and what I'd like to replicate in XAML

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33465775/2681948) and its answer will help.

Comment: Hi Romasz, thanks for your response, but the suggested question/answer that you linked still requires creating a subclass of DataTemplateSelector with logic in there - I was more looking for a solution that avoided dipping into C# code - if that is even possible. The only thing that the DataTemplateSelector subclass adds is an If statement, I thought there might be a succinct way to do it in XAML

Comment: What I need is a solution similar to accepted answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected) but not using Style Triggers as they aren't available in UWP

Answer (score 2):

you need to use overwrite SelectTemplateCore of Data template. Change your view model like this.
Below code will helps you.

```
public class SampleViewModel : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ClassAListViewItemTemplate{ get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ClassBListViewItemTemplate{ get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsData = item as SampleClass; // add your Data class 
        if (itemsData.IsAddButton == false) // define any property to select the datatemplate
        {
            return ClassAListViewItemTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return ClassBListViewItemTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

Add your two datatemplates to one key, and give the key to ItemTemplateSelector property in gridview.

```
<viewModels:SampleViewModel x:Key="FeedbackTempateSelector"
    ClassAListViewItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClassAListViewItemTemplate}"
    ClassBListViewItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClassBListViewItemTemplate}">

</viewModels:SampleViewModel>
```

Comment: On return-statements it says: Cannot implecitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.Ui.Xaml.DataTemplate'